# Is it possible to allocate a specific length for a column in unix?

Tags: python, shell, unix, awk, sed

I want to print all the columns in a proper format, is there any command for allocating a column with some specific length.I used "\t" which gives me below output(`File.txt`) but I want `Required_output.txt`.

File.txt

```
Dec 2    amlfx_HDW_20161202.txt  01:05   12.70
Dec 2    amltxn_HDW_20161202.txt         01:06   85.72
Dec 2    amlsecmstr_HDW_20161202.txt     01:05   0.000
```

Required_output.txt

```
Dec 2    amlfx_HDW_20161202.txt          01:05   12.70
Dec 2    amltxn_HDW_20161202.txt         01:06   85.72
Dec 2    amlsecmstr_HDW_20161202.txt     01:05   0.000
```

I used the command, I want that space management in $11 and $10 in awk statement.

```
find . -mtime 1 -iname "aml*" -ls | awk '{print $8,$9"\t",substr($11,3,100)"\t",$10"\t",substr($7=$7/(1024^2),1,5)}'
```

Comment: `awk` can do formatted printing like `printf("%-20s", $1)`, and Python can do that like `print("{:-20s}".format(value)`. Try and succeed

Comment: Your question is ill posed though, since you asked to get a specific formatting, but then throw in tags like Python, awk, sed and even shell (which one?) and unix (the latter has nothing to do with your question). That is too broad. Generally, some attempts of actual code are much clearer to find out where precisely you are stuck, so try something yourself first.

Comment: You have no upvotes for any question you have asked, most are downvoted, you've only accepted 1 answer and you have a total rep of 3 after multiple Q/A. Clearly posting on SO as you've been doing isn't working for you. Why not read [ask] and see if you can learn how to have better luck asking questions here?

Comment: @Evert, I tried with your answer but didn't success with a test as below awk '{printf $1"\t",("%-40s", $2),$3}', can you please have a look on my question's bottom line ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: I don't understand: it appears your question has been solved with sirfz's answer.

Comment: Have you tried bringing everything *inside* the printf function? '{printf("%s\t%-40s%s\n", $1,$2,$3)}'.

Comment: @Evert, Now it was working fine, you are awesome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) like this:

```
In [33]: c1 = "hello"

In [34]: c2 = "world"

In [35]: print "{:10s}{:10s}".format(c1, c2)
hello     world
```

`{:10s}` basically aligns your text to the left with a size of 10 characters.

Comment: I don't see any Python code in your question, try the suggested formatting syntax and post your code if you're still unable to get the desired output.

Comment: find . -mtime 1 -iname "aml*" -ls | awk '{print $8,$9"\t",substr($11,3,100)"\t",$10"\t",substr($7=$7/(1024^2),1,5)}

Answer (score 0):

test data:

```
$ cat test.txt
Dec 2 amlfx_HDW_20161202.txt  01:05 12.70
Dec 2 amltxn_HDW_20161202.txt 01:06 85.72
Dec 2 amlsecmstr_HDW_20161202.txt 01:05 0.000
```

awk script:

```
BEGINFILE{
   # FILENAME: built-in var
   # get max width of each column
   while(getline < FILENAME)
   {
        for(j=1;j<=NF;j++)
        if(width_ary[j-1]<length($j))
            width_ary[j-1] = length($j)
   }
}

{
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)
    {
        if (i < NF)
        {
            # to get format string like this: '%-10s    '
            fmt = sprintf("%%-%ds    ", width_ary[i-1])
            printf(fmt, $i)
        }
        else{
            fmt = sprintf("%%-%ds    \n", width_ary[i-1])
            printf(fmt, $i)
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
$ awk -f t.awk test.txt
Dec    2     amlfx_HDW_20161202.txt         01:05    12.70
Dec    2     amltxn_HDW_20161202.txt        01:06    85.72
Dec    2     amlsecmstr_HDW_20161202.txt    01:05    0.000
Dec    12    amlsecmstr_HDW_20161212.txt    02:05    10.10
```

AWK version:

```
awk -V
GNU Awk 4.1.3, API: 1.1
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2015 Free Software Foundation.
```

Comment: I tried your logic but it was not success and I am getting this error  awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ unexpected newline or end of string
./awk.ksh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./awk.ksh: line 6: `    for(j=1; j<=NF; j++)'

Comment: sorry, I should show you awk version of my box.   here is awk verison:

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This issue is fixed from my end :)